# Create columns name from rows?

Tags: sql-server, pivot

I have this data :

```
name      | coulmnnuber
Newyork   | 1
washington| 2
denmark   | 3
Holand    | 4
```

Data should look like this :

```
1           2           3          4
New york    Washington  denmark    Holand
```

Comment: Does nobody search before posting questions?

Answer (score 4):

You can use an aggregate function with a CASE expression to convert the rows of data into columns:

```
select 
  max(case when coulmnnuber = 1 then name end) [1],
  max(case when coulmnnuber = 2 then name end) [2],
  max(case when coulmnnuber = 3 then name end) [3],
  max(case when coulmnnuber = 4 then name end) [4]            
from yourtable;
```

See [SQL Fiddle with Demo](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/17789/3)

Or you can use the PIVOT function:

```
select [1], [2], [3], [4]
from yourtable
pivot
(
  max(name)
  for coulmnnuber in ([1], [2], [3], [4])
) piv;
```

See [SQL Fiddle with Demo](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/17789/2)

Comment: EXCELLENT That Only I can Say. No Words. Perfect